# Point new domain to existing sub directory and mask URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an existing website at domain1.com, and we eventually started a new website at domain1.com/newsite. Now we'd like to give that site its own domain name but keep it at the current location, so we purchased a new domain name (domain2.com) and pointed it to domain1.com/newsite

Including this in our htaccess works perfectly for redirecting all URLs,

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ http://domain1.com/newsite/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]

But, I'd like to mask the URL in the address bar so that visitors only see domain2.com along with whatever page they're requesting in their browser. domain2.com/foo for example which would display content from domain1.com/newsite/foo

All solution I've been able to find either accomplish what I already have in place, or provide domain masking by only showing domain2.com in the address bar without anything following it.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) and alternate document roots:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/newsite
    ServerName domain2.com
    # other directives
</VirtualHost>
```

This assumes the **DocumentRoot** of **domain1.com** is **/www**.